# django-modeltranslation become a already exists field in translatable

Tags: django, translation

I'm using *django-modeltranslation* to translate models in my app. I've a model which I've sync with the db with migrate command. Also I've a lot of records for that model.

```
class Home(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
```

Of course, at this point, I can retrieve description field from db

```
h = Home.objects.first()
h.description # --> "This home is near to..."
```

Now, I want to become the *description* field translatable using django-modeltranslation. I've follow de guide, I've registered the model for translation in the *translation.py* file, Finally I've executed *makemigrations* and *migrate* commands. This added to my db, in the *home* table, the fields **description_en** and **description_es**, as my available languages are **en** and **es**, the former is the default.

At this point I need to populate the description_en field which is the default for any query, I tried

```
Home.objects.all().update(description_en=F('description'))
```

but it doesn't work because when it tries to access to the *description* field it in fact is trying to access to *description_en*, and it is empty:

```
h = Home.objects.first()
h.description # --> '' Empty?!!!
```

I've check if the data still in the db and they are!

**My question is**: if *description* data still in db, and *h.description* retrieve me in fact *h.description_en*, How can I populate *description_en* for all data in *description* field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reading this [django-modelstranslation fallback original field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28974133/django-modelstranslation-fallback-original-field-value), I realized of existence of management command that is shipped with modeltranslation and it populate the default lang: **python manage.py update_translation_fields**